# ¿Por qué al crear una fecha obtengo un mes diferente?

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy realizando una actividad y he colocado un jcalendar a mi formulario, quiero que cuando seleccione un jtable dicho calendario vuelva a colocar la fecha que habia guardado. Logre capturar dicho valor y crear una fecha a partir de los strings, el año y dia quedan correctos, pero el mes me da el mes + 1, es decir, si coloco mes febrero 02 fecha_nac estara guardando mes marzo 03 y a su vez en el jcalendar se estara mostrando dicho mes.

```
        int fila = this.table_candidatos.getSelectedRow();
        String fecha = elect1.getCandidatos().get(fila).getFecha_nac();

        String[] tiempo = fecha.split("-");
        Calendar fecha_nac = Calendar.getInstance();
        fecha_nac.set(Integer.parseInt(tiempo[0]), Integer.parseInt(tiempo[1])-1, Integer.parseInt(tiempo[2]));
     // System.out.println(tiempo[0] + " " + tiempo[1] + " " + tiempo[2]);
     // System.out.println(fecha_nac.getTime());
        this.calendar_fecha.setCalendar(fecha_nac);
```

Comment: de dónde sacas el JCalendar que estás usando?

Comment: Hola como estas, utilizo el jcalendar 1.4 y lo que subi es un fragmento de codigo.

Comment: Es que no sabemos qué es elect1 ni `getFecha_nac()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema que tienes es de la Clase `Calendar` que tenia que solucionar los problemas con `Date` y solo complico más todo, porque `Calander` tiene muchos problemas de diseño que la hacen nada intuitiva.

Lo que te sucede es que en `Calendar` Enero es `0` no es `1`, si, se lo que estas pensando a quien se le ocurrió que era una buena idea que los meses deben ir de 0-11 pero al darle formato al Calendar `yyyy-MM-dd` si le pones `1` en la salida mostrara `2` el mes que es correcto, el problema es solo en el método `set`, entonces a la fecha que obtienes en `String fecha = elect1.getCandidatos().get(fila).getFecha_nac();`  le debes de restar uno al mes que pases al método `set`.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Prueba {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int anio = 2022;
        int mes = 2;
        int dia = 25;

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(anio,Calendar.JANUARY,dia);
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(c.getTime())); // Imprime Marzo

        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.set(anio,mes-1,dia);
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(c2.getTime())); // Imprime Febrero

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias y tienes completa razon, al restarle 1 al mes pude obtener la fecha correcta.